# Javascript Check if local Script exists

Tags: javascript, html

Supposing I have a script that might not always be present how do I make sure not to call if it doesn't exist?

HTML section

```html
<script src="js/model.js"></script>
<script src="js/view.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

```
(function(model, view, script){
"use strict";
     document.addEventListener('loadata', function (e) {
         script.loadData(e.detail);
 });
```

Controller.js section

How do I stop Controller from making use of the script if it doesn't exist?

And how would I remove it from the HTML file?

EDIT: I also make one or 2 calls to functions in script from Controller

Comment: To stop using script, one suggestion would be to set a global var in script which then you can search for in controller to be sure script was loaded and executed

Comment: So  var script = (function(){ "use strict"; var check =true;....                  How would I access this in Controller? and wouldnt (function(model, view, script){
 be problematic aswell

Comment: To make sure the flag is available everywhere you set it inside script like `window.scriptFlag = true` then you can check for it anywhere in the code with something like `if( typeof window.scriptFlag != "undefined" )`  although I'm not sure why would you not be sure it is loaded, that seems to me a bad design logic. And of course it would cause trouble in that code, you would need first to check if `script` exists and then use it.

Comment: Well I only really want to use the script to load data if present.  The user might remove it so then I cant make use of script then. Do you see a better way of handling the scenario?

Comment: I don't get what must be present for the script to load, but if this is not a site with ajax-navigation I think you should load all the needed js files, trust that they will be there when needed and just trigger them when user interaction require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

you can add a flag within script.js (in global scope)

```
var myCustomFlag = true;
```

and in controller you can check if this has run:

```
if (window.myCustomFlag == true) {
//stop your controller etc
}
```

**Solution 2**

You can check for the existence of the  tag  using querySelectorAll

in your controller

```
var scriptIsLoaded = document.querySelectorAll("script[src='js/script.js']").length > 0;
if (scriptIsLoaded ){
 //stop your controller etc
}
```

Comment: Ahh so this would allow me to access the element and modify it if needed.     Any ideas for my first question?

Comment: what is the first question ?

Comment: How do I stop Controller from making use of the script if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks, would (function(model, view, script){  cause an error if script is not present?